# Couldn't get all the text for System-Wide search functionality using algolia-search-plugin with gatsby

Tags: algolia, gatsby-plugin-mdx

I aim to integrate a system-wide search feature into my project, utilizing Gatsby alongside Strapi. While experimenting with the Algolia search plugin, I encountered a limitation—it only retrieves data from markdown components. How can I extend this functionality to encompass all text across different components stored in my Strapi database?

I tried this

`const escapeStringRegexp = require("escape-string-regexp");

const pagePath = `content`;
const indexName = `Search`;

const pageQuery =   `{     pages: allMarkdownRemark {       edges {         node {           id           frontmatter {             title           }           excerpt         }       }     }   }`;

function pageToAlgoliaRecord({ node: { id, frontmatter, excerpt } }) {
return {
objectID: id,
...frontmatter,
excerpt
};
}

const queries = [
{
query: pageQuery,
transformer: ({ data }) => data.pages.edges.map(pageToAlgoliaRecord),
indexName,
settings: { attributesToSnippet: [`excerpt:5000`] }
}
];

module.exports = queries;
`